# JSP cannot parse form input to integer

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

**I have a Vector Magazines where I keep all the titles of the magazines. I created a form so that people can choose the magazines they want.**

```
...

<form action="MagForm.jsp">
<table>
<%
Vector Magazines; //Already populated with titles

for(int i = 0; i < Magazines.size(); i++)
{
%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mags" value="<%=i%>">
            <%out.println(Magazines.get(i)); %><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
<%
}
%>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</table></form>

<%
String select[] = request.getParameterValues("mags");

for(int i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
{
    out.println(select[i]);
}
%>
```

**For the above codes, I can successfully get the result of Select.
But when I modify it to:**

```
<%
String select[] = request.getParameterValues("mags");
int a;
for(int i = 0; i < select.length; i++)
{
    a = Integer.parseInt(select[i]);
    out.println(a);
}

%>
```

**It gives me an error message: For input string "on". Why can't I parse the string array to integer?**

Comment: You need to **read** request parameters only when the **submit** is pressed.

Comment: Yes I understand that I need to press submit to get the values. Before the modification, when I press submit, select[i] will be printed out. But after modification, I cannot parse select[i] to interger. Thanks

Comment: You've incorrect code. On first request, `select` will be null (and your code wont compiled) and on subsequent request you get 'on' value because select[index] consists value 'on' instead of 0,1,2 etc.